# Is boycotting or hurting businesses an instance of hard power?

Tags: terminology, protests, power

As an example of what I'm talking about, here's what's happening in Myanmar:

1. Since some professors in our medical universities did not join the [civil disobedience movement](https://www.voanews.com/east-asia-pacific/how-myanmars-civil-disobedience-movement-pushing-back-against-coup), surgeons, dentists and doctors posted on Facebook that they will not buy medical equipment and materials from sellers (shops) who sell to all those (professors) who do not join the civil disobedience movement.
2. People in Myanmar no longer support or buy products from commercial enterprises related to or owned by military families.

Looking at these two cases, what kind of "power" are these kinds of things an example of?

[Hard Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_power) is defined as:

> Hard power is the use of military and economic means to influence the behavior or interests of other political bodies

So, since this is a kind of economic pressure, can I say that hurting businesses or boycotting is hard power? Or is it better described as [soft power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_power)? Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "hard power"? Is there an objective definition?

Comment: There are political terms: [Soft Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_power), [Hard Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_power) and [Smart Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_power).

Comment: The words looked biased but they're not. It happens.

Comment: You've tagged this as [myanmar], but it sounds like you're asking a general question about the definition of "hard-power" and just using the protests in Myanmar as an example. Is this accurate? Or are you looking for a Myanmar specific answer?

Comment: yes, I'm asking a general question about power using an example happening in Myanmar. Let me know if the tag [myanmar] needs to be removed.

Comment: It is bad practice to immediately checkmark an answer and instead is better to wait a couple days to see what answers come along.

Comment: yeah, I was in rush to know about it. Yeah, I will see more better answers after a couple days and checkmark the final best one.

Comment: @eps it is also bad practice to criticizing accepting an answer on a question you plan on answering.

Answer (score 20):

No.  I can see why one might think so, since Hard Power is often defined as using "military or economic means to influence/coerce an entity," but there are two other important elements to hard power: it must be a formal power, that is to say it must be codified in law somehow; and it must be a positive power - it must be an action taken.

Economic sanctions, which are the legal version of a boycott, are a form of hard power, because they are formal (they're actions of law), they are positive (they *do* something, in this case establish mandates to enforce prohibitions), and they are economic (and sometimes military when it comes down to it).

A Boycott, however, while economic in nature, is neither formal - it's choices made by private citizens, not entities of law; nor is it positive - it's not *doing* something, it's ***not*** doing something. Refraining from something, a negative act, is always going to be Soft Power (in the Hard/Soft duality).

Boycotts aren't even properly thought of as 'hurting' a business, because such an understanding presupposes that businesses are *entitled* to your custom and thus you are acting against their property rights by refusing to transact with them.  In actuality, no such duty to transact exists - this is a definitive hallmark of Soft Power: it involves social forces.

Boycotts are more akin to not inviting someone to your birthday party, because they're an asshole than they are to economic sanctions.  Virtually all diffuse, citizen actions fall into Soft Power for the same reasons.

Comment: Boycotts can certainly involve coercion and coersive actors, but it wouldn't probably be called hard or soft power simply because those words are usually reserved for state actors engaging in international diplomacy and even then the terms aren't very rigorous.

Comment: The term "Soft Power" gets used to describe political power exercised by non-state actors all the time, though. It's often used to scoop up what Baumer and Van Horn termed "Boardroom Politics" or "Living Room Politics" and so on.  There's major players in the processes of state actions that don't have formal powers. All of which merely reinforces your point that these terms aren't very rigorous.

Comment: Aren't "hard vs. soft" and "small vs. big" two dimensions of power, rather than the same dimension? If "small" was always "soft", then the distinction was useless.

Comment: In "pure" economics, a business actually _is_ entitled to your custom, _if_ they are the best bidder. - If you start to factor politics into economics, it stops being economics, doesn't it? - So, if you chose to not take the best offer, because of non-economic reasons, you are hurting a business. Not much, but if enough people do it, there should be a non-negligible effect on the business. - I think that your distinction between "active" and "passive" is arbitrary.

Comment: @I'mwithMonica What do you call "pure" economics?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin "pure" economics is the pseudoscience that assumes the existance of a _homo economicus_... ;)

Comment: @I'mwithMonica Isn't it already a political decision to model economics this way? ;)

Comment: @I'mwithMonica Focusing purely on price is a simplification. It doesn't account for long-term and network effects. While a boycott of the best bidder could be an altruistic political effect, it can also be viewed as taking a short-term hit for a long-term gain. E.g. if it changes the country's economic policies, you'll do better under the new regime. Another example: buying solar power is expensive now, but we need first adopters so that prices will come down and we'll all win in the future.

Comment: The distinction being made here between an economic sanction as "doing something" and a boycott as "not doing something" seems strained.  The end result of either is "not doing something."  The mandate is only a step in the middle.  Indeed, I might have a step in the middle of my boycott, where I publish a document calling on others to do the same.  By the logic being applied to government, I have now done something.

Comment: Although it occurs to me that the real difference between a sanction and a boycott is whether or not it is coercive.  A sanction coerces others to not do business.  A boycott is voluntary.

Comment: I guess that's why the quoted definition says "influence [...] **other** political bodies"? You need to be a political body, not just private citizens, for this to apply at all?

Comment: @Manuel As noted elsewhere, classically the Hard/Soft distinction was only applied to state actors. Since a slew of non-state actors' behavior has been described as 'Soft' using this model, it presupposes there is a private-citizen 'Hard' power.  If, instead of calling for people to boycott, an armed militia was going around using threat of force to keep people away from a business? I'd call that non-state hard power. It lacks the 'formal' aspect, but since we're in the weeds already why not argue that an organized militia becomes a state actor? The whole model is of limited use anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Frame challenge: hard and soft power are largely outdated cold war era terms used for state actors and international diplomacy and has no real relevance today. I have never heard of internal politics being talked about in "hard" and "soft" power terms, it's just not a useful way to frame things.

For example someone might argue the BDS (Boycott, Divestment and Sanctions for Israel) is soft power, another might say it uses coercion and "hard" power but the real answer is who cares, it's pointless semantics.